# myFlatten in JS - recursive call not given expected return

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and currently trying to solve some of the classic coding algorithms to get familiar with the language. I come from basic Ruby bg. I am currently working on a hard-coded version of "flatten" function and I am not getting the desired output. I have revised my logic multiple times and I can't figure out what is my mistake.

Here is my code :

The input of the function is a multidimensional array and the output supposed to be a flattened version of it.I am getting the same input array.

```
 function  myFlatten(arr){
  var flattenArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i +=1){
    var ele = arr[i];
    if(Array.isArray(ele)){
      flattenArr.push(myFlatten(ele));
    }else {
      flattenArr.push(ele);
    }
  }
  return flattenArr;
}
```

Comment: `myFlatten` returns an array. `flattenArr.push(myFlatten(ele));` So you're not flattening anything.

Comment: Rigth... I am having some trouble figuring out how to push just the elements tho. I thought all of the elements will get pushed into the flattenArr once they were not Arrays... hence, when they "hit" the else...

Comment: You can use `concat`

Comment: So weird... I tried that also and it wouldn't work. Is this syntax correct: flattenArr.concat(myFlatten(ele));    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ES6, you could spread the values as parameters for pushing ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

```
flattenArr.push(...myFlatten(ele));
//              ^^^
```

Comment: It worked this way and now I am reading about the spread syntax parameter. I was not familiar with it at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it on this way

```
function myFlatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
     return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? myFlatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
   }, []);
}
```